# For loop exiting before I want it to

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so I have 2 arrays, one consisting of 20 teams and one consiting of the league fixtures. I then have a very large for loop which loops through each single fixture and allocates the points, goals scored, goals allowed etc to each team. Everything works so long as there isn't more than 20 fixtures in the fixture array. Once I put the 21st fixture in the array my table crashes and I'm not sure why.

```
var teams = [
 {id: 1, name: "AC Milan", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 2, name: "AS Roma", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 3, name: "Atalanta", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 4, name: "Bologna", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 5, name: "Benevento", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 6, name: "Cagliari", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 7, name: "Chievo", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 8, name: "Crotone", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 9, name: "Fiorentina", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 10, name: "Genoa", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 11, name: "Hellas Verona", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 12, name: "Inter", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 13, name: "Juventus", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 14, name: "Lazio", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 15, name: "Napoli", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 16, name: "Sampdoria", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 17, name: "Sassuolo", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 18, name: "SPAL", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 19, name: "Torino", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
{id: 20, name: "Udinese", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];


var fixtures = [
//matchday1
{match: 1, Homeid: 13, Awayid: 6,    Homescore: 3, Awayscore: 0},
{match: 1, Homeid: 11, Awayid: 15,    Homescore: 1, Awayscore: 3},
{match: 1, Homeid: 3,  Awayid: 2,    Homescore: 0, Awayscore: 1},
{match: 1, Homeid: 14, Awayid: 18,   Homescore: 0, Awayscore: 0},
{match: 1, Homeid: 4,  Awayid: 19,   Homescore: 1, Awayscore: 1},
{match: 1, Homeid: 12, Awayid:9,     Homescore: 3, Awayscore: 0},
{match: 1, Homeid: 20, Awayid: 7,    Homescore: 1, Awayscore: 2},
{match: 1, Homeid: 16, Awayid: 5,   Homescore: 2, Awayscore: 1},
{match: 1, Homeid: 17, Awayid: 10,   Homescore: 0, Awayscore: 0},
{match: 1, Homeid: 8, Awayid: 1,   Homescore: 0, Awayscore:3 },
//matchday2
{match: 1, Homeid: 10, Awayid: 13,    Homescore: 2, Awayscore: 4},
{match: 1, Homeid: 5, Awayid: 4,    Homescore: 0, Awayscore: 1},
{match: 1, Homeid: 2,  Awayid: 12,    Homescore: 1, Awayscore: 3},
{match: 1, Homeid: 19, Awayid: 17,   Homescore: 3, Awayscore: 0},
{match: 1, Homeid: 1,  Awayid: 6,   Homescore: 2, Awayscore: 1},
{match: 1, Homeid: 7, Awayid:14,     Homescore: 1, Awayscore: 2},
{match: 1, Homeid: 9, Awayid: 16,    Homescore: 1, Awayscore: 2},
{match: 1, Homeid: 8, Awayid: 11,   Homescore: 0, Awayscore: 0},
{match: 1, Homeid: 15, Awayid: 3,   Homescore: 3, Awayscore: 1},
{match: 1, Homeid: 18, Awayid: 20,   Homescore: 3, Awayscore: 2}
```

];

```
for (var i = 0; i < fixtures.length;i++)      //For loop which calculates the Home and Away results for each team
{  
    if (fixtures[i].Homeid == 1)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j <teams.length; j++)
        {
            if (teams[j].id == fixtures[i].Homeid)
                {
                    teams[j].GP += fixtures[i].match;
                    teams[j].GF += fixtures[i].Homescore;
                    teams[j].GA += fixtures[i].Awayscore;
                    teams[j].GD = teams[i].GF - teams[i].GA;

                     if (fixtures[i].Homescore > fixtures[i].Awayscore){
                        teams[j].W += 1;

                }
                     else if (fixtures[i].Homescore < fixtures[i].Awayscore)
                {
                        teams[j].L += 1;
                }
                     else if (fixtures[i].Homescore == fixtures[i].Awayscore){
                           teams[j].D += 1;

                }
                }
        }
    }

     if (fixtures[i].Awayid == 1 )
     {
        for (var j = 0; j <teams.length; j++)
        {
            if (teams[j].id == fixtures[i].Awayid)
                {
                    teams[j].GP += fixtures[i].match;
                    teams[j].GF += fixtures[i].Awayscore;
                    teams[j].GA += fixtures[i].Homescore;
                    teams[j].GD = teams[i].GF - teams[i].GA;

                     if (fixtures[i].Homescore < fixtures[i].Awayscore){
                        teams[j].W += 1;

                }
                     else if (fixtures[i].Homescore > fixtures[i].Awayscore)
                 {
                        teams[j].L += 1;
                }
                     else if (fixtures[i].Homescore == fixtures[i].Awayscore){
                           teams[j].D += 1;

                }
                }
        }
    }

    if (fixtures[i].Homeid == 2)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j <teams.length; j++)
        {
            if (teams[j].id == fixtures[i].Homeid)
                {
                    teams[j].GP += fixtures[i].match;
                    teams[j].GF += fixtures[i].Homescore;
                    teams[j].GA += fixtures[i].Awayscore;
                    teams[j].GD = teams[i].GF - teams[i].GA;

                     if (fixtures[i].Homescore > fixtures[i].Awayscore){
                        teams[j].W += 1;

                }
                     else if (fixtures[i].Homescore < fixtures[i].Awayscore){
                        teams[j].L += 1;
                }
                     else if (fixtures[i].Homescore == fixtures[i].Awayscore){
                           teams[j].D += 1;

                }
                }
        }
    }

     if (fixtures[i].Awayid == 2 )
     {
        for (var j = 0; j <teams.length; j++)
        {
            if (teams[j].id == fixtures[i].Awayid)
                {
                    teams[j].GP += fixtures[i].match;
                    teams[j].GF += fixtures[i].Awayscore;
                    teams[j].GA += fixtures[i].Homescore;
                    teams[j].GD = teams[i].GF - teams[i].GA;

                     if (fixtures[i].Homescore < fixtures[i].Awayscore){
                        teams[j].W += 1;

                }
                     else if (fixtures[i].Homescore > fixtures[i].Awayscore){
                        teams[j].L += 1;
                }
                     else if (fixtures[i].Homescore == fixtures[i].Awayscore){
                           teams[j].D += 1;

                }
                }
        }
    }
```

And so on and so on until it loops through each team

```
for (var x = 0; x < teams.length; x++)                //Calculates Total 
points for all teams
{
    teams[x].pts = teams[x].W * 3 + teams[x].D;
}

window.onload = function()
{
var tableContainer = document.querySelector("#table");
var table = "";

teams.sort(function(a,b)
{return b.pts - a.pts});

for (var i = 0; i<teams.length; i++)
{
    table += "<tr>" + 
                 "<td>" + teams[i].name + "</td>"+
                 "<td>" + teams[i].GP + "</td>"+
                 "<td>" + teams[i].W + "</td>"+
                 "<td>" + teams[i].D + "</td>"+
                 "<td>" + teams[i].L + "</td>"+
                 "<td>" + teams[i].GF + "</td>"+
                 "<td>" + teams[i].GA + "</td>"+
                 "<td>" + (teams[i].GF - teams[i].GA) + "</td>"+
                 "<td>" + ( (teams[i].W * 3) + teams[i].D) + "</td>"+
            "</tr>";
}
    tableContainer.innerHTML+=table;
};
```

Comment: can you post the error you get?

Comment: It's not an error, my table no longer appears

Comment: the fixures array is never closed and the last item is trailed by a comma (same for the teams array)

Comment: and your function is SO much overcomplecated!

Comment: Sorry I miscopied it.

Comment: `teams[j].GD = teams[i].GF - teams[i].GA;` .. i is fixture index, j is team index - as you have 20 teams and 21 fixtures, when j == 20 (the 21st index) teams[i] will be UNDEFINED

Comment: And I don't consider it overcomplicated at all. I just loop through the home and Away results for each team.

Comment: if I copy your code and execute it, I get `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`

Comment: I suppose the line "points for all teams" shouldn't be before opening the loop body and its declaration. (Last code snippet).

Comment: sorry, but this code is so crap... realy. if you check if fixtures[i].homeid equals one... why do you need to search for the team that matches fixures[i].homeid? You know it HAVE TO BE 1... you're not considering the DRY princip of programming.

Comment: added a simple code fragment to solve the same problem you try to solve in hundreds of lines. I will delete it after some time, because it wasn't asked, but please take a look at it and think about it. Your code is a WAY to complecated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few places where you do something like

```
teams[j].GD = teams[i].GF - teams[i].GA;
```

Now, `i` is index of `fixtures`, and `j` is index of `teams`

as you have 20 teams and 21 fixtures, when j == 20 (the 21st index) teams[i] will be UNDEFINED